# 8GB Hyper-V host, but guests can't use more than 6GB?

Tags: hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V 2012 R2 host with 8GB RAM. My guest VMs have 4096, 1024, and 768 MB of ram. When I try to add a new one with 256MB, it says it can't allocate enough RAM.

Is Hyper-V itself really taking up 25% of the memory? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to verify by checking task manager.

Comment: Task manager says the rest of the RAM is cached. It only has about 6.5 allocated on the host before I attempt to add the guest with 256MB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Emulation does take up some extra memory, some proportional to the memory used some not. Hyper V takes up 1G of memory and depending on how your graphics card is configured you may have some memory tied up with that.

Buy some more ram!

Comment: I can't buy more RAM. It's an old machine that is maxed out at 8GB. The graphics are integrated, and I think it may take up about 128MB if I recall. I just didn't think it would suck of that much though. Seems like there are cached items in Hyper-V Server's memory that I could free up in order to allow guests with more RAM.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768529%28BTS.10%29.aspx. It provides a better explanation than I did.